# Como tomar una variable dentro de un echo en PHP

Tags: php, echo

tengo un problemilla espero que puedan ayudarme, bien en un sistema que estoy desarrollando mediante una consulta a una base de datos obtengo algunos datos como fecha de compra, total, envio, entre otros, estos datos los guardo en varibles como

```
$order_id, $net_total, $shipping
```

etc.

Despues construyo un formulario en HTML y lo muestro mediante "echo", aqui esta el problema.

Construye bien el formulario pero no me toma las variables, lo que hace es imprimir directamente el texto por ejemplo $order_id

Ya intente haciendo `<?=$order_id?>, <?php $order_id?>` y sigue solo mostrando el texto de la variable pero no la variable en si.

Osea muestra: $order_id
EN vez de: 2240

Les dejo el codigo y espero me puedan ayudar, soy nuevo en esto de PHP y por mas que lei documentacion no di con la respuesta.

```
if(!empty($order_id)){
    echo '<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="legal_name" placeholder="Nombre o Razon Social" required>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Correo Electronico" required>
    <input type="text" name="tax_id" placeholder="RFC" required>
    <input type="text" name="street" placeholder="Calle" required>
    <input type="text" name="exterior" placeholder="Numero Exterior" required>
    <input type="text" name="interior" placeholder="Numero Interior" >
    <input type="text" name="neighborhood" placeholder="Colonia" required>
    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Ciudad" required>
    <input type="text" name="municipality" placeholder="Municipio" required>
    <input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="Codigo Postal" required>
    <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="Estado" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="country" placeholder="Pais" value="MEX" required>
    <select name="tax_system">
    <option value="601">General de Ley Personas Morales</option>
    <option value="603">Personas Morales con Fines no Lucrativos</option>
    <option value="605">Sueldos y Salarios e Ingresos Asimilados a Salarios</option>
    <option value="606">Arrendamiento</option>
    <option value="608">Demás ingresos</option>
    <option value="609">Consolidación</option>
    <option value="610">Residentes en el Extranjero sin Establecimiento Permanente en México</option>
    <option value="611">Ingresos por Dividendos (socios y accionistas)</option>
    <option value="612">Personas Físicas con Actividades Empresariales y Profesionales</option>
    <option value="614">Ingresos por intereses</option>
    <option value="616">Sin obligaciones fiscales</option>
    <option value="620">Sociedades Cooperativas de Producción que optan por diferir sus ingresos</option>
    <option value="621">Incorporación Fiscal</option>
    <option value="622">Actividades Agrícolas, Ganaderas, Silvícolas y Pesqueras</option>
    <option value="623">Opcional para Grupos de Sociedades</option>
    <option value="624">Coordinados</option>
    <option value="628">Hidrocarburos</option>
    <option value="607">Régimen de Enajenación o Adquisición de Bienes</option>
    <option value="629">De los Regímenes Fiscales Preferentes y de las Empresas Multinacionales</option>
    <option value="630">Enajenación de acciones en bolsa de valores</option>
    <option value="615">Régimen de los ingresos por obtención de premios</option>
    <option value="625">Régimen de las Actividades Empresariales con ingresos a través de Plataformas Tecnológicas</option>
    <option value="626">Régimen Simplificado de Confianza</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="tax_system" placeholder="Regimen fiscal" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="payment_method" placeholder="Metodo de Pago" value="PUE" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency" placeholder="Moneda" value="MXN" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="use_cfdi" placeholder="Uso del CFDI" value="G01" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="description_product" placeholder="Descripcion del producto" value="Productos para mascotas" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="product_key" placeholder="Clave de Producto" value="10111300" required>
    <select name="payment_method">
    <option value="01">Efectivo</option>
    <option value="03">Transferencia Electronica de fondos</option>
    <option value="04">Tarjeta de credito</option>
    <option value="28">Tarjeta de debito</option>
    <option value="99">Por definir</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="order_id" placeholder="Numero de Orden" value="<?php $order_id?>" readonly>
    <input type="text" name="net_total" placeholder="Neto" value="<?=$net_total?>" readonly>
    <input type="text" name="tax_total" placeholder="IVA" value="$tax_total" readonly>
    <input type="text" name="shipping_total" placeholder="Envio" value="$shipping_total" readonly>
    <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Total" value="$total_sales" readonly>
    <input type="text" name="num_items_sold" placeholder="Cantidad de productos" value="$num_items_sold" readonly>


    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se supone que desde el principio ya estabas en un contexto de PHP:

```
if(!empty($order_id)){
    echo '<form action="" method="post">
```

Por tanto, no necesitarías seguir abriendo bloques PHP en partes como esta:

```
value="<?php $order_id?>"
```

Pero, tampoco puedes meter la variable directamente, dado que no estás en un contexto de comillas dobles.

Una solución sería concatenar, usando el punto, por ejemplo:

```
if(!empty($order_id)){
      echo '<form action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="legal_name" placeholder="Nombre o Razon Social" required>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Correo Electronico" required>
      <input type="text" name="tax_id" placeholder="RFC" required>
      <input type="text" name="street" placeholder="Calle" required>
      <input type="text" name="exterior" placeholder="Numero Exterior" required>
      <input type="text" name="interior" placeholder="Numero Interior" >
      <input type="text" name="neighborhood" placeholder="Colonia" required>
      <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Ciudad" required>
      <input type="text" name="municipality" placeholder="Municipio" required>
      <input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="Codigo Postal" required>
      <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="Estado" required>
      <input type="hidden" name="country" placeholder="Pais" value="MEX" required>
      <select name="tax_system">
      <option value="601">General de Ley Personas Morales</option>
      <option value="603">Personas Morales con Fines no Lucrativos</option>
      <option value="605">Sueldos y Salarios e Ingresos Asimilados a Salarios</option>
      <option value="606">Arrendamiento</option>
      <option value="608">Demás ingresos</option>
      <option value="609">Consolidación</option>
      <option value="610">Residentes en el Extranjero sin Establecimiento Permanente en México</option>
      <option value="611">Ingresos por Dividendos (socios y accionistas)</option>
      <option value="612">Personas Físicas con Actividades Empresariales y Profesionales</option>
      <option value="614">Ingresos por intereses</option>
      <option value="616">Sin obligaciones fiscales</option>
      <option value="620">Sociedades Cooperativas de Producción que optan por diferir sus ingresos</option>
      <option value="621">Incorporación Fiscal</option>
      <option value="622">Actividades Agrícolas, Ganaderas, Silvícolas y Pesqueras</option>
      <option value="623">Opcional para Grupos de Sociedades</option>
      <option value="624">Coordinados</option>
      <option value="628">Hidrocarburos</option>
      <option value="607">Régimen de Enajenación o Adquisición de Bienes</option>
      <option value="629">De los Regímenes Fiscales Preferentes y de las Empresas Multinacionales</option>
      <option value="630">Enajenación de acciones en bolsa de valores</option>
      <option value="615">Régimen de los ingresos por obtención de premios</option>
      <option value="625">Régimen de las Actividades Empresariales con ingresos a través de Plataformas Tecnológicas</option>
      <option value="626">Régimen Simplificado de Confianza</option>
      </select>

      <input type="text" name="tax_system" placeholder="Regimen fiscal" required>
      <input type="hidden" name="payment_method" placeholder="Metodo de Pago" value="PUE" required>
      <input type="hidden" name="currency" placeholder="Moneda" value="MXN" required>
      <input type="hidden" name="use_cfdi" placeholder="Uso del CFDI" value="G01" required>
      <input type="hidden" name="description_product" placeholder="Descripcion del producto" value="Productos para mascotas" required>
      <input type="hidden" name="product_key" placeholder="Clave de Producto" value="10111300" required>
      <select name="payment_method">
      <option value="01">Efectivo</option>
      <option value="03">Transferencia Electronica de fondos</option>
      <option value="04">Tarjeta de credito</option>
      <option value="28">Tarjeta de debito</option>
      <option value="99">Por definir</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="order_id" placeholder="Numero de Orden" value="'.$order_id.'" readonly>
      <input type="text" name="net_total" placeholder="Neto" value="'.$net_total.'" readonly>
      <input type="text" name="tax_total" placeholder="IVA" value="'.$tax_total.'" readonly>
      <input type="text" name="shipping_total" placeholder="Envio" value="'.$shipping_total.'" readonly>
      <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Total" value="'.$total_sales.'" readonly>
      <input type="text" name="num_items_sold" placeholder="Cantidad de productos" value="'.$num_items_sold.'" readonly>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>';
}
```

Hay otras opciones posibles, como el uso de [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.printf.php), que podría ser útil para este caso. `printf` recibe dos argumentos: la cadena, con marcadores donde irían las variables, y las distintas variables que sustituirían cada marcador.

Por ejemplo:

```
if(!empty($order_id)){
      printf('<form action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="legal_name" placeholder="Nombre o Razon Social" required>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Correo Electronico" required>
      <input type="text" name="tax_id" placeholder="RFC" required>
      <input type="text" name="street" placeholder="Calle" required>
      <input type="text" name="exterior" placeholder="Numero Exterior" required>
      <input type="text" name="interior" placeholder="Numero Interior" >
      <input type="text" name="neighborhood" placeholder="Colonia" required>
      <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Ciudad" required>
      <input type="text" name="municipality" placeholder="Municipio" required>
      <input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="Codigo Postal" required>
      <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="Estado" required>
      <input type="hidden" name="country" placeholder="Pais" value="MEX" required>
      <select name="tax_system">
        <option value="601">General de Ley Personas Morales</option>
        <option value="603">Personas Morales con Fines no Lucrativos</option>
        <option value="605">Sueldos y Salarios e Ingresos Asimilados a Salarios</option>
        <option value="606">Arrendamiento</option>
        <option value="608">Demás ingresos</option>
        <option value="609">Consolidación</option>
        <option value="610">Residentes en el Extranjero sin Establecimiento Permanente en México</option>
        <option value="611">Ingresos por Dividendos (socios y accionistas)</option>
        <option value="612">Personas Físicas con Actividades Empresariales y Profesionales</option>
        <option value="614">Ingresos por intereses</option>
        <option value="616">Sin obligaciones fiscales</option>
        <option value="620">Sociedades Cooperativas de Producción que optan por diferir sus ingresos</option>
        <option value="621">Incorporación Fiscal</option>
        <option value="622">Actividades Agrícolas, Ganaderas, Silvícolas y Pesqueras</option>
        <option value="623">Opcional para Grupos de Sociedades</option>
        <option value="624">Coordinados</option>
        <option value="628">Hidrocarburos</option>
        <option value="607">Régimen de Enajenación o Adquisición de Bienes</option>
        <option value="629">De los Regímenes Fiscales Preferentes y de las Empresas Multinacionales</option>
        <option value="630">Enajenación de acciones en bolsa de valores</option>
        <option value="615">Régimen de los ingresos por obtención de premios</option>
        <option value="625">Régimen de las Actividades Empresariales con ingresos a través de Plataformas Tecnológicas</option>
        <option value="626">Régimen Simplificado de Confianza</option>
      </select>

      <input type="text" name="tax_system" placeholder="Regimen fiscal" required>
      <input type="hidden" name="payment_method" placeholder="Metodo de Pago" value="PUE" required>
      <input type="hidden" name="currency" placeholder="Moneda" value="MXN" required>
      <input type="hidden" name="use_cfdi" placeholder="Uso del CFDI" value="G01" required>
      <input type="hidden" name="description_product" placeholder="Descripcion del producto" value="Productos para mascotas" required>
      <input type="hidden" name="product_key" placeholder="Clave de Producto" value="10111300" required>
      <select name="payment_method">
        <option value="01">Efectivo</option>
        <option value="03">Transferencia Electronica de fondos</option>
        <option value="04">Tarjeta de credito</option>
        <option value="28">Tarjeta de debito</option>
        <option value="99">Por definir</option>
      </select>
      
      <input type="text" name="order_id" placeholder="Numero de Orden" value="%s" readonly>
      <input type="text" name="net_total" placeholder="Neto" value="%s" readonly>
      <input type="text" name="tax_total" placeholder="IVA" value="%s" readonly>
      <input type="text" name="shipping_total" placeholder="Envio" value="%s" readonly>
      <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Total" value="%s" readonly>
      <input type="text" name="num_items_sold" placeholder="Cantidad de productos" value="%s" readonly>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>',
    $order_id,$net_total,$tax_total,$shipping_total,$total_sales,$num_items_sold);
}
```

Hay más opciones, como podrían ser rodear la cadena de comillas dobles (en cuyo caso puedes meter dentro variables directamente), o la apertura cierre de bloques PHP / HTML combinados (advierto que esto produce un código confuso, y sólo es recomendable en bloques amplios de contenido HTML).

Para este caso, lo más simple es concatenar o usar `printf`.

Comment: Excelente me funciono perfecto, si lo habia intentado el poner .$order_id. y no me funciono, pero ahora veo que me falto encerrarlo en comillas simples, muchas gracias, todos los dias se aprende algo nuevo.

Comment: @ArmandoVázquez me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Para este caso `printf()` puede ser interesante (revisa la respuesta editada). Sólo tendrías que poner un marcador, como `value="%s"`  en cada parte donde deban ir variables, y pasar al final cada variable. Esto ayuda a tener un código más claro, sin tantas concatenaciones.

Comment: le hechare un ojo a printf(), y si eso ayuda a tener un codigo menos complicado claro que lo usare.

Comment: @ArmandoVázquez `printf` es muy simple de usar. Puedes probar primero con algo simple como esto: `$datoA=1; $datoB=2; printf('value="%s", value="%s"',$datoA,$datoB);`  y cuando veas cómo funciona lo incorporas a tu código. Hay también una función parecida que es `sprintf` que funciona igual, pero ésta te guarda el resultado en variables, útil cuando construyes tu contenido en varias partes, mientras que `printf` se usa para impresión directa.